# Hide an Instance of a Window

Tags: c#, wpf, instance, show-hide

how do I hide an Instance of a Window which was created in an Method, in another Method?

I have a Login Window with a button "Register" and when you click that, the Register-Window is opening, and the Login-Window is hiding (That is working fine). 
The Problem now is, i have on the Register-Window a Button "Back" which should hide the Register Window and Show the Login Window.
I Can show the Login Window with : "Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();", but i dont know how to hide the Register-Window. Normally i would just go for "Regis.Hide()", but i can´t do that because i have the instance of Regis in the Method, which opens the Register Window.

I understand, that if i create a second instance in the second Method and hide this, that that wont work because there are 2 seperate instances now.
But as i said, i dont know how i should do this either.

OpenRegistrationGui:

```
ICommand _RegisterBack;
public void Open()
{
    Application.Current.MainWindow.Hide();
    Register regis = new Register();
    regis.Show();
}

public ICommand RegisBackCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_RegisterBack == null)
            {
                _RegisterBack = new RelayCommand(
                    param => Back()
                    );
            }
            return _RegisterBack;
        }
    }

public void Back()
{
    Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    //I Want to Hide the Regis here, but i cant use the Instance from above.
}
```

MyViewModel:

```
OpenRegistrierungsGUI RegisGUI = new OpenRegistrierungsGUI();
public ICommand RegisBack
    {
        get => RegisGUI.RegisBackCommand;
        set => RegisBack = RegisGUI.RegisBackCommand;
    }
```

The Same Thing is with the Open() Method.

The Result i want is simply that the Register Window is hiding and the Login Window shows off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

I fired the Open() Method (Which worked perfectly).
When I wanted to fire the Back() Method I accidentally created an Instance of "OpenRegistrationGui" and tried to Close it, which it obviousely can´t, because its another Instance.
I made the Property "RegisBackCommand" Static and fired it now directly from the ViewModel, which works now.

Anyway...  Thank you all for your fast Answers and help!!!

Answer (score 2):

This will resolve your issue by making `regis` a member variable that the whole class has access to...

```
private Register regis;

public void Open()
{
    Application.Current.MainWindow.Hide();

    // Create the register window, if it doesn't exist
    if (regis == null)
    {
        regis = new Register();
    }

    regis.Show();
}

public void Back()
{
    // hide the register window, if it exists
    if (regis != null)
    {
        regis.Hide();
    }

    Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
}
```

There are different ways of doing this, but this one ensures only one instance of the register window and gives you the show/hide ability you need.

Comment: First thanks for the fast answer. but sadly when i am doing this, i am getting an System.NullReferenceException when the Method Back() fires. The Value of regis is null.

Comment: I was assuming that `Back()` would only fire *after* the registration form was shown.  I'll just add a second null check in there for a sanity check.

Comment: You are right, the Back() can only fire after Registration is shown. The Button only exists on the Form Registration. The Null check is perfect, but still it wont hide the Registration Form.

Comment: In that case something else is going on to stop this working, because that code should work without problem.  Is there only one instance of the class that has the `Open()` and `Back()` methods, and how are they called?  Also, is `Regis` actually a windows form?

Comment: Yes, there is only that one instance of Registration. Registration is not WinForms, its WPF and regis is just the name of the Instance.

Comment: What about the code in your question though?  That must be in a different class - is there only one instance of that class?

Comment: For Info: I got the Registration Form which got the Button "Back" the Button is Bound to my ViewModel. My ViewModel fires an ICommand which fires the Method Back().

Comment: So the `Back()` function is in the `Register` class?

Comment: No, i´ve made another class in which i´ve got the Open(), Back() and the ICommands. MyViewModel then basicly just got properties which copies the value of the ICommands to fire them from the Class ViewModel. (I prefer it more to have a ViewModel with only Properties)

Comment: If the `Open()` and `Back()` methods are in the same class and there is only one instance of that class then there is no reason that this code won't work.  If it doesn't then there's definitely something else causing your problem.

Comment: I´ve edited the Question. That is basically everything which is in that Class (the same is with the open() Method). All I´ve done thene is to Bind my Button to the "RegisBack" Property in the ViewModel.

Comment: I still see nothing that would stop this working.  You basically have one variable that is a reference to an instance of `Register` and you use that variable in both the `Open()` and `Back()` methods.  That's literally how you do what you're asking.  Sorry, but if this doesn't work in your example then I do not know why.

Comment: Well thank you anyway! appreciate your help :) I will continue checking if I can find the Issue and will write it here if I got it.

Answer (score 0):

simply use `regis.hide();` hopefully its work for you.

```
private Register regis;
 public void Back()
        {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
        regis.hide();
        }
```

here you want to use one function variable into another

Comment: `regis` only exists inside the `Open()` method because that's where it's declared.  Nothing outside that method knows that variable.

Comment: hi Archer please vote me positive i improved my formatting.

Comment: It wont work for me, im getting an SystemNullReferenceException on regis when Back() fires.

Answer (score 0):

Declare regis globally than initialize it in method where you first you use it .

> In this way there will be only one instance of regis .

Now you can do

```
regis.Hide()
```

or

```
regis.Show()
```

in any method of your class